# Windows Git Server and Linux Git Client

Tags: linux, windows, git

I have a bare git repository set up on my Windows 2016 server, and I have a repository on a CentOS Linux client that I'm trying to push to the Windows server repo over http. I keep getting a "Repo doesn't exist" error. I have verified that the repo is accessible via http from a browser (I see all the repo files displayed). I copied that same URL and setup a remote on my CentOS box and it can't find it.

I read somewhere that it might be a permissions issue. Has anyone had this issue before, and has anyone been able to fix it?

I can't seem to find an article that explains how to properly set up this type of environment. I can only seem to find a Linux server to Windows client setup.

**Update**

To be more clear on my setup: I downloaded git from https://git-scm.com/. I have an IIS 7 webserver hosting the git repository currently. I'm attempting to make a http connection from CentOS. Do I really need third-party software to make it work, or will it work using just IIS and git?

Comment: A git repository on a MS-Windows server. Wow...

Comment: How are you hosting the git repository? Which software package are you using for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your Git repository hosting service is setup.

- [Gogs, for instance](https://gogs.io/docs/installation), supports both https and SSH
- [GitBlit](http://gitblit.com/) also support http(s): see "[Using the HTTP/HTTPS transport](http://gitblit.com/setup_transport_http.html)"

Both would explain how to setup HTTP access for Git repository on Windows (since they are multi-platform)

Using IIS: "[How to set up a git repository accessible through http on IIS](https://cedric-dumont.com/2016/03/14/how-to-set-up-a-git-repository-accessible-through-http-on-iis/)", it uses [**`jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server`**](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server).

> Do I NEED a third part software to make it work, or will IIS and git work on their own? I'd prefer to not install anything else, unless necessary

Yes, it is preferable. As illustrated with this [old project](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/06/25/hosting-a-git-server-under-iis7-on-windows/), you need to call [`git-http-backend`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend) one way or the other.

Comment: Do I NEED a third part software to make it work, or will IIS and git work on their own?  I'd prefer to not install anything else, unless necessary.

Comment: @JohnHaffenreffer It is easier with a third-party. And the installation is minimal (for gogs, it is just an exe to copy, that's it). I only saw an iis setup in 2010 (http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/06/25/hosting-a-git-server-under-iis7-on-windows/)

Comment: @JohnHaffenreffer another example of third-party (using iis): https://cedric-dumont.com/2016/03/14/how-to-set-up-a-git-repository-accessible-through-http-on-iis/